# C How to escape specific characters in printf?

Tags: c, printf

As the title says it i want to escape some specific characters from `printf()`. I remember something like:

```
char string[]="asdasdadss";
printf("%[^s]s",string);
```

To output:

> adadad

Any ideas that can help. Thanks.

Comment: `printf` doesn't work like that - you'll have to do whatever processing to remove the `'s'` character from the string *before* passing it to `printf`.

Comment: @BarışSedefoğlu you are recalling incorrectly. Review the `printf` format string documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%[` syntax is for `scanf()`, not `printf()`.  You need to modify your string before calling `printf()`.